# Prove $\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\right)\geq 0$ without using derivative

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, definite-integrals, alternative-proof, hyperbolic-functions

Claim :

Let $0\leq x$ then prove (without using derivative) that :

$$\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\right)\geq 0$$

Trick :

We have using integral :

$$\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\right)=\int_{}^{}\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\,dx$$

So we have :

$$0\leq \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{\tanh(x)}\,dx=\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(a)}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\tanh(a)}\right)$$

I'm really curious to see another proof :

Question :

Have you an alternative proof without derivative ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you can simplify this by setting $y = \sqrt{\tanh(x)}$. Then you just need to show that $\tanh^{-1}(y) \geq \tan^{-1}(y)$ for $0 \leq y < 1$.

Comment: I think that's a trivial consequence of $\tanh t<t<\tan t$ for $t\in(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Can you make an answer ? Thanks!